# onbeforeunload event is not working when user not click inside the body of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want call one function when user open any page and without click on that page, he just close the page.

I have tried this to put one button and click on that button using coding after page loading is complete , but it is not working.

I am follow this link. **[W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload)**

In this link , when you not click in result portion and reload page then it will not display alert , but when you click result portion and reload page then it will displaying a alert.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `onbeforeunload` is attached to the `<iframe>`'s `window` object, and when you do unload the main page, this event won't fire unless you had focus on this iframe.

Same will happen with StackSnippet here:

```js
onbeforeunload = e => true;
```

```html
<span>click to toggle iframe's focus</span>
```

Comment: same thing is not working in html page at localhost , i have to click in to page for trigger `beforeunload` event , in localhost i am not using any iframe.

Comment: @KetanModi do you mean like clicking the Tab's "x" from an other tab in chrome? I think this is a browser's implementation, not ruled by specs. In both FF and chrome you need at least one interaction with the page. (which makes sense since this feature is to provide a safety check before user could loose data he entered, if no action, no data he entered lost)

Comment: Ps: this is what the yellow part of MDN's article says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifications.